# Field Type missing from Contentful APi response

Tags: contentful

I have setup my application to consume the content deliver API using the contentful SDK, its all hunky dory untill now when i realized the **fieldType** for each field in the **content model** is missing in the API response. 
Am i missing something? I am providing more details about the API and its response below -

[API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B90Uj.png)

The issue is if i dont know the the field type, i would have to ask the content writers to stick to a specific template and order of the fields instead of rendering the fields dynamically as you parse the response.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not get the field types in the response, but you do get the content type id. It is expected that you already know what type of fields a specific content type contains.

The content type id can be found in the `sys.contentType.sys.id` property of each entry. With this information you could select which template to render.

If you still need to dynamically decide how to render based on the type of a field you would have to resort to the [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator to check what the type of each field is. You would lose out on the possibility to differentiate between specific Contentful properties though as they would all be returned as `object`.

You could also call the content type endpoint to fetch the entire content model from the Contentful API. http://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/space-id/content_types/

This would give you a the field each content type contains and the type of each field in the following structure:

```
{
  "sys": {
     // sys properties
  },
  "displayField": "productName",
  "name": "Product",
  "description": null,
  "fields": [
    {
      "id": "productName",
      "name": "Product name",
      "type": "Text",
      "localized": true,
      "required": true,
      "disabled": false,
      "omitted": false
    },
    {
      "id": "slug",
      "name": "Slug",
      "type": "Symbol",
      "localized": false,
      "required": false,
      "disabled": false,
      "omitted": false
    },
  // further fields
  ]
}
```

It would result in multiple API calls to get the information you want though.

Comment: Thank you @Robban. Is this an oversight from the contentful team?Because the dynamic rendering would be the first choice of rendering the contentful data and fieldType is all that was needed, we could have just read the fieldType and rendered appropriate Component on the client, with this the developer didn't have to worry about the what the model contains. But thank you for the clarification.

Comment: You're welcome. No I would not consider it an oversight. I just realized there's actually a way to get the field type if you'd really want to. I'll update the answer with that.

Comment: Yep @Robban tried that, the disadvantage with that endpoint is it wont resolve Links for me, so if i have references to other content models in my model, i will have to make separate calls to retrieve each Link with its linkType id which is not feasible,